# Special Relativity: Temporal order of events depends of the frame of reference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames

Suppose we have two events, A and B, in a inertial frame $ S $, with position four-vectors: $(ct_{A}, \vec{x_{A}})$ and $(ct_{B}, \vec {x_ {B}})$. If $$ \Delta S ^ {2} = c ^ {2} (t_ {A} - t_{B}) ^ {2} - (\vec {x_{A}} - \vec {x_{B}}) ^ {2} < 0,$$ with $ t_ {B}> t_ {A} ,$ then there is a frame $ S '$ such that $ t_{B}' <t_{A}' $? If so, what is the minimum speed $ V $ of $ S '$ with respect to $ S $?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).